# push_back vector of vector

Tags: c++

i got some problem with vector of vector. in my program, i have defined a dynamic memory for vector of vector and did the resize and push_back the elements.

```
vector<vector<double> > *planes = new vector<vector<double> >
planes->resize(s_list->size()); // size of another vector that i need to use
vector<int>::iterator s_no;
for(s_no=s_list->begin(), int i=0; s_no!=s_list->end(); s_no++, i++){){
                        //where i i the indices of planes

     //some codes for computing length, width

     planes->at(i).push_back(lenght);
     planes->at(i).push_back(width);
}
```

it works and i got the print of all values what i added. then, i changed new vector defining part as follows

```
vector<vector<double> > *planes = 
              new vector<vector<double> >(s_list->size(),vector<double>(2,0.0))
```

and removed the resize part. then, when i got the print out of vector of vector, i got 0 values for all. could you please rectify this issue.

Comment: Please provide a *complete*, *compilable* example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: How are you printing it and how are you setting the values? `push_back` appends and your initial vectors start out with zeros in them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `at` instead of `push_back`

```
 planes->at(i).at(0)=lenght;
 planes->at(i).at(1)=width;
```

push_back() adds new items, therefore you end with with 4 items in each vector. You should use at() to modify the existing entries.

Better still is to use a `vector< pair<double,double> >`, assuming you will always have two items.

Comment: @ Aaron>>> thanks; but, i got some error massages >>'struct std::pair<double, double>' has no member named 'at' > --<<. may you clarify vector< pair<double,double> >. what is the meaning of "pair"? should it be the word vector? can i use vector<pair<double,double> > *planes = new vector<pair<double,double> > with out saying size of outer vector? Could you please also comment me which method is best and, would it be speeding up the processing if i use 'at' insted of push_back. (because i have long data set)